# Nuxt handle redirect after deletion without errors : beforeUpdate direction not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I have this nuxt page `/pages/:id`.

In there, I do load the page content with:

```
content: function(){
  return this.$store.state.pages.find(p => p.id === this.$route.params.id)
},
subcontent: function() {
  return this.content.subcontent;
}
```

But I also have an action in this page to delete it. When the user clicks this button, I need to:

1. call the server and update the state with the result
2. redirect to the index: `/pages`

```
// 1
const serverCall = async () => {
  const remainingPages = await mutateApi({
    name: 'deletePage',
    params: {id}
  });
  this.$store.dispatch('applications/updateState', remainingPages)
}

// 2
const redirect = () => {
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/pages'
  });
}
```

Those two actions happen concurrently and I can't orchestrate those correctly:

I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subcontent' of undefined`, which means that the page properties are recalculated **before** the redirect actually happens.

I tried:

1. `await` server call then redirect
2. set a `beforeUpdate()` in the component hooks to handle redirect if `this.content` is empty.
3. delay of 0ms the server call and redirecting first
4. 

```
subcontent: function() {
  if (!this.content.subcontent) return redirect();
  return this.content.subcontent;
}
```

None of those worked. In all cases the current page components are recalculated first.

What worked is:

```
redirect();
setTimeout(() => {
  serverCall();
}, 1000);
```

But it is obviously ugly.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you hinted, using a timeout is not a good practice since you don't know how long it will take for the page to be destroyed, and thus you don't know which event will be executed first by the javascript event loop.

A good practice would be to dynamically register a 'destroyed' hook to your page, like so:

```
methods: {
    deletePage() {
        this.$once('hook:destroyed', serverCall)
        redirect()
    },
},
```

Note: you can also use the 'beforeDestroy' hook and it should work equally fine.

Comment: A potential problem with this answer is it relies on the component being destroyed *after* the redirect occurs, which is probably fine for the OP's use case. It also *always* calls `serverCall()` when the page gets destroyed (is it assumed that when the component is destroyed that the store must also delete the corresponding page?).  The root problem to me is that `subcontent` is dereferencing `undefined`, and that should be addressed.

Comment: The serverCall method is not always called since the 'destroyed' hook is only registered in the page when the deletePage method is called. This means that any other redirect will not trigger the serverCall method. You are right that addressing the problem of accesing the content and subcontent in a safe way is important, but relaying on it can generate an user experience problem since the user can, for a period of time, be in a page with no content (Until Nuxt's redirect is finished). That issue is specially important when the next page makes a server call in the asyncData method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sequence of events occurring:

1. `serverCall()` dispatches an update, modifying `$store.state.pages`.
2. `content` (which depends on `$store.state.pages`) recomputes, but **`$route.params.id` is equal to the ID of the page just deleted**, so `Array.prototype.find()`  returns `undefined`.
3. `subcontent` (which depends on `content`) recomputes, and dereferences the `undefined`.

One solution is to check for the `undefined` before dereferencing:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    content() {...},
    subcontent() {
      return this.content?.subcontent
                         

      // OR
      return this.content && this.content.subcontent
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-vuex-mutation-ixrur?file=/src/pages/Page.vue:615-654)